# given a list of mp4, generate fmp4 and concatenate

Tags: video, ffmpeg

my input is a list of mp4 (for example each one is 10s), each mp4 will have correct timestamp, for example the second mp4 represents from 10s - 20s data.

To simulate my input, I generate a list of mp4 this way

```
ffmpeg -i ../origin-long-video.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -f segment -segment_time 10 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)" -reset_timestamps 0 videos/output_%03d.mp4
```

Note I use reset_timestamps 0 so that the timestamp is preserved.

Then I convert each mp4 to fragment mp4 by using

```
ffmpeg -y   -i videos/output_001.mp4   -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)"   -sc_threshold 0   -s 1280x720   -c:v libx264 -b:v 1500k   -c:a copy   -hls_time 100   -hls_playlist_type vod   -hls_segment_type fmp4   -hls_segment_filename "hls1/file%d.m4s"  -copyts hls1/index.m3u8
```

The above cmd is for the first mp4 file, i did same operation for other mp4 in the list.
Note I used a large hls_time so that each mp4 will result in one fmp4, and also I use copyts to preserve the timestamp.

Then I want to concatenate for example the 2nd and the 3rd fmp4 to generate one mp4, I used

```
cat init.mp4 > rs.mp4
cat 2nd fmp4 >> rs.mp4
cat 3rd fmp4 >> rs.mp4
```

However when trying to play the generated rs.mp4, it is 20s black screen then 10s video (corresponding to the 3rd mp4).

I tried another approach which just generated a list of fmp4 directly like this:

```
ffmpeg -y   -i ../origin-long-video.mp4   -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)"   -sc_threshold 0   -s 1280x720   -c:v libx264 -b:v 1500k   -c:a copy   -hls_time 10   -hls_playlist_type vod   -hls_segment_type fmp4   -hls_segment_filename "videos/file%d.m4s"   videos/index.m3u8
```

And then if I concatenate the 2nd and 3rd generated fmp4 use the same way above, the result mp4 plays well.

I wonder what is the difference between the generated fragment mp4 of the two approach so that they leads to different behavior when concatenation. Thank you!